# jQuery to dynamically resize divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html

I'm using the media thumbnails that twitter bootstrap v2.3 has in their CSS library. You can see what I'm working on [here](http://beanstalkwebsolutions.com/portfolio-overview).

Here is the jQuery I'm using:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function () {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    var divs = jQuery(".thumbnail");
    jQuery.each(divs, function () {
        var height = jQuery(this).height();
        if (maxHeight < height) maxHeight = height;

    });
    divs.css('min-height', maxHeight + 'px');
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    var divs = jQuery(".thumbnail");
    jQuery.each(divs, function () {
        var height = jQuery(this).height();
        if (maxHeight < height) maxHeight = height;

    });
    divs.css('min-height', maxHeight + 'px');
});
</script>
```

Basically my goal was since each thumbnail had different heights and I wanted them to all be equal heights, this script gives them all the same min-height in CSS on load, and everytime the screen is resized based on whichever thumbnail has the greatest height.

I got all that to work, but now the problem I can't figure out is when you drag the screen to smaller/bigger sizes and the min-height becomes very large, I have no code to decrease the min-height so they thumbnail divs look way too big. Does anyone have any code suggestions for me so the divs will all have equal height, but never get too big?

And if you set the **height** css property rather than **min-height**, the solution doesn't work for my original goal because the text paragraphs end up extending outside the divs.

Comment: its related to this line "divs.css('min-height', maxHeight + 'px');". maxHeight is only ever increasing each time you resize. Maybe you need to know the window size to detect when to reduce the height of the images. To be a little clearer when you increase the browser size the images increase in size when you decrease the browser size nothing happens to resize the images.

Comment: What all browsers you need to support? How about using CSS `flexbox`? http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/19/css3-flexible-box-layout-explained/

Comment: Thomas Harris, yes your clarification is correct. If I use the window size method do you have an example of code you can show me?

Comment: Vanga Sasidhar, I need to support all desktop and phone browsers except really old versions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On window resize you can set the min-height of the divs again, like this:-

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  if($( window ).height() < 300){
  $( "div" ).css({min-height: 300px});
 } else {
  $( "div" ).css({min-height: 600px});
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I would upvote but I need 15 reputation to do so.